# Overriding default jsdoc -> .d.ts conversion to get rid of ...args: any[]

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript-declarations

When using `tsc` to generate declarations only, JSDoc tags are used to infer types etc.

Is it possible to override the types inferred from the JSDoc?

Specifically, for a function using `arguments`, [tsc will always add](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#var-args-parameter-declaration-inferred-from-use-of-arguments) an `...args: any[]` vararg parameter to the function declaration. I want to override that to get rid of it since `arguments` is only used for legacy reasons and there should be no vararg arguments to the function.

Example:

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 */
function myLegacyFunction(x) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  return 42;
}
```

... will render

```
export function myLegacyFunction(x: number, ...args: any[]): number;
```

Note that even if I do use `@param` to document `x` and leave out `args`, it's still added implicitly.
I also tried explicitly listing `args` as type `...never`, but that also didn't help:

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @param {...never} args
 */
function myLegacyFunction(x) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  return 42;
}
```

How can I make `tsc` understand that this function should simply be:

```
export function myLegacyFunction(x: number): number;
```

(Using typescript 4.2.3.)